# A word for "when someone does something for your benefit while you are active on something else"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if your mom cleans your room while you are busy outside she is ***-word-*** cleaning your room.

The word "proactively" is stuck on my mind but it's not directly related and it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: "nevertheless", maybe? Despite...nevertheless(ly).

Comment: _You were busy outside; your mom was busy cleaning the room._

Comment: How about "she *surprised* me by cleaning my room"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thoughtful** or **kind** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/thoughtful)

> given to or made with heedful anticipation of the needs and happiness of others

For example:

> If your mom cleans your room while you are busy outside she is *kindly* cleaning your room.